# push_back an element into a vector of an another structure vector's back()

Tags: c++, vector, struct

```
struct Thing
{
    int id;
    std::vector<int> v2;
};

std::vector<Thing> v1;
int main()
{
    int n;
    cin>>n;

    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        Thing pic;
        cin>>pic.id;
        v1.push_back(pic);
        int x;
        cin>>x;
        v1.back().v2.push_back(x);
    }
}
```

v1 is not an empty vector. I can't understand the line `v1.back().v2.push_back(x);` what's the actual meaning of this line

Comment: `v1` is an empty vector, there is no back element.

Comment: I already told that v1 is not an empty vector.. It contains elements.

Comment: @IshRak In the code you show `v1` is empty no matter how much you wish it be not. What is the question?

Comment: In the code you've posted here, it is empty.  If you have code where it is not, then you need to post that code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`v1.back()` is the last element of `v1` with the type of `Thing`

`v1.back().v2` is the `v2` member of that element with the type of `vector<int>`

So you are calling the `push_back()` on a `vector<int>` with an `int` what is fine

Note that if `v1` is empty then `v1.back()` is UB

Edit:
`v1.back().v2.push_back(x);` is kind of like

```
{
Thing& t=v1.back();
vector<int>& v=t.v2;
v.push_back(x);
}
```